# Javascript Prompt() text is partially hidden in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to display a "larger than normal" amount of text in a prompt() box. When calling the javascript prompt() function in Internet Explorer 11, a large portion of my text is being hidden. It seems to only support 2 lines of text. Chrome, Firefox and Opera seem to work fine. This seems to be just an IE issue.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jfielaidof/c9zz70zj/)

```
prompt("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum     has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
```

I am only able to see this text "*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when*". The rest is not displayed.

I'm afraid I already know the answer, but is there a reason why this is happening? I would prefer to use the prompt() and not use a custom modal.

Comment: The easiest solution is to not use a prompt box.

Comment: this browser effs up even a cup of coffee..this is unreal..in an ideal world I'd protest against supporting the browser itself, not the prompt thing..

Comment: You should use an alternative like the JQuery dialog.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides If you know of any serious issue we're failing at, please feel free to ping me personally and I'll work towards getting it fixed.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides OP is trying to use a feature that was obsolete 15 years ago, with an input it was never intended to handle. This feature was implemented in IE long before most other major browsers even _existed_, and I think the IE dev team has better things to do than focus on issues like this.

Comment: @JLRishe The *amount of small issues like this* is what the problem is with IE. The prompt is also the *only* way to ask a question and also block the thread. It contains 2 buttons and text. Limiting the text to 2 lines for *no apparent reason* is what puts me off.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides If you're trying to block the thread in the first place, in the year 2015, then you're going about things the wrong way.

Comment: By focusing on the not-so-important part of my reply and skipping the rest, you have successfully convinced me to forgive and love IE. Hooray IE!

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides As Jonathan has already said, if you have any _valid_ concerns about IE, please let him know. He's a PM on the IE team, and is more than capable of getting changes into the product. And regarding this: _Limiting the text to 2 lines for no apparent reason is what puts me off._ Nobody specifically made a 2-line limit. The IE prompt is in a non-expanding dialog that only fits two lines of text. So that is the reason. It was only ever intended to show short prompts and went out of fashion in favor of other methods long before anyone saw a need to show a prompt longer than that.

Comment: @JLRishe well, thats not too bad of an argument. Still they'd have to try hard to convince me to trust it as a browser after all these years but I admit that PM's in these forums are a pleasant surprise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably not use `window.prompt` to begin with. It is largely frowned upon due to the fact it blocks the thread, and thus can halt your application. The web today has moved towards leveraging the asynchronous nature of JavaScript; this should distance us from things like `alert`, `prompt`, etc.

Presently the `prompt` is not supported in Immersive Internet Explorer ("Metro"), Internet Explorer on the xbox, or Windows Web Applications (formerly Windows Store Applications). Instead, you are encouraged to leverage third-party tools and libraries (such as Bootstrap, jQuery UI, etc) for these types of needs.

All of this being said, it is a genuine difference between Internet Explorer and other modern browsers, and as a result I have opened up an issue internally for the IE team to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

The IE version of prompt does not dynamically resize.

You should only be using prompts for small messages, not whole paragraphs.
like

e-mail:

or

username:

You should have any explanation stuff inline on the web page. or better yet don't use prompt's at all and use inline forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these alerts, even simpler than modals:

If you use Bootstrap, Bootboxjs is for you:
http://bootboxjs.com/

Sweetalert is also simple and cool:
http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert