# Internet Explorer pop up message truncated in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this code in my javascript section

```
function abc() {
    return (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this from your list?"));
}
```

I have this code at my code behind

```
btn_CallAbc.Attributes["onclick"] = "return abc();"
```

But pop up message truncated when I click on the button as picture below.

[[image: Pop up message truncated screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chqGL.png)

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: looks like a font scaling issue in the browser. try inserting a line break `\n` somewhere in the middle of the prompt text.

Comment: I have tried inserting \n in the middle/in front/at the end of the message but message still truncated

Comment: seems like it has to be `\r\n` for IE.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. I tried your suggestion but still the same

Comment: weird. do you not even get a second line? or are there two lines but it still truncates?

Comment: yes. Message will break into two lines but still truncated. I'm using IE 11.407.17134.0

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26746254/1132334) not very helpful though. what is your screen resolution and font scaling? any non-standard graphics settings in Windows or in the browser advanced options?

Comment: Are you able to repro the issue on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Good news @dlatikay, pop up will display full message after i change font and scaling from 125% to 100%. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error with dlatikay for some time, he asked what is my screen resolution and font scaling, any non-standard graphics settings in Windows or in the browser advanced options.

I check my font and scaling % which is set to 125%. Pop up display full message after set it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

The modal dialog box is supposed to accomodate to the size of the text it contains, up to a reasonable limit. On a screen with scaling factor 100% it works for me with your unchanged string, the box is just wide enough. So this is probably a font scaling issue. A quick-and-easy fix can be achieved by inserting a line break, as there is sufficient vertical space available:

```
window.confirm('Are you sure you want to\r\ndelete this from your list?');
```

Tested on Windows 10 in IE 11.187.14393.0

[image]